# Is there an alternative python function does as PHP include() function?

Tags: python, module, import

My python project path `/project` and these are its files :

```
/project/test.py
/project/templates/
/project/includes/
/project/includes/config.py
```

```
# config.py
import os
template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
```

when I used execute() function to include config.py from test.py  , the `/project/includes/config.php` file was executed and the result was returned to `/project/includes/test.py` so template_path variable was saved as `/project/includes/templates/` and templates folder would not be found there .
I want a function to include `/project/includes/config.py` from `/project/test.py` and execute all functions in `/project/includes/config.py` through `test.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a (empty) file `__init__.py` in `includes`.

In `test.py`, call `config.py` by doing an `import`.

`from includes import config`

So if there is a function say `foo` in `config`, you will call it like:

`config.foo()`

Refer to the documentation (as pointed out by [The MYYN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533953/is-there-an-alternative-python-function-does-as-php-include-function/4533961#4533961))

Comment: Is this statement "from includes import config" must be at the beginning of file ?

Comment: It should be at the beginning but you can have it anywhere you want. But PEP8 (Python style guide) recommends: `Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any modulecomments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.`

Answer (score 3):

In Python you don't *include*, you *import*, also you don't import *files and directories*, you import *modules and packages*, which are often (but not always) files and directories present somewhere in the Python path. Therefore the common practice is to put all your modules in a package which the user should place in the Python path, and then import the modules from there. Importing *files* is possible but discouraged.

If your `config` module is a real module part of your library, internal configuration or site configuration, you need to create a new package named as your project is named, put the `config` and other modules inside it. Also note that because of the module/package structure used in Python, creating a project with an `includes` directory for the modules inside it isn't going to work very well.

If your `config.py` file is supposed to be user configuration, you can look at the `ConfigParser` module, or use the third-party `cfgparse`.

Answer (score 2):

You usually *include* code from other files (called modules) via `import`.

- [Documentation on modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)
- [Reference: import statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)

Comment: Although that's closer to `require_once`. There's no real Python equivalent (thankfully!).

Comment: "import" must be at the beginning of file ?

Comment: No, `import` can be used anywhere, although it is common practice to put all imports on top.