# Prevent code duplication by importing files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When using PHP, I write code in a separate file that I include using `require_once()` or `include_once()`. Is there something similar in Python as well?

I read this answer: [Is there an alternative python function does as PHP include() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533953/is-there-an-alternative-python-function-does-as-php-include-function/4533961#4533961)

The file I want to run in `run.py`. The file I want to include is `funcs.py`. The `funcs.py` file is located inside a folder called `includes`. The folder `includes` and `run.py` are in the same location.

I created an empty file `__init__.py`.
I use `from includes import funcs`. However, I get the error `No Module named includes`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You sure there's no typo in the folder names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import a file from a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory)

Comment: @user202729. Yes, I have double checked the names. :)

Comment: Where is the empty `__init__` file located?

Comment: @Tomerikoo That did not resolve the error either. The `__init__` file is inside includes folder.

Comment: I don't think you can do `from includes import funcs`. Does `import includes.funcs` work?

Comment: And are you sure that the folder name you posted in the question is the same as those in the file system?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Aren't they the same?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I tried them both, None of them work. I am running the file `run.py` from the command line. Does that change anything?

Comment: @user202729 Yes, they are the exact same files. :)

Comment: But but... `inlucdes` and `includes` is definitely not the same.

Comment: Hehe sorry about that. It was just a typo in the question. The actual folder is definitely `includes`. :)

Comment: Add more info. How are you running the file? Where are you placing the init file?

Comment: @user202729 The file relies on a larger project I installed using `pip` install manimgl`. Will that affect the import because it worked on other file I created.

Comment: @user202729 I run the file using `manimgl run.py Examples -o --file_name pce-02` where `Examples` is a class inside `run.py` and other parameters are for `manimgl`.

Comment: Let's say there is a function `foo` in `funcs.py` then you need to do `import includes.funcs` and then call `funcs.foo()`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I get the error on the import line itself. So, I don't even get to the point where I could call `funcs.foo()`.

Comment: Sorrybuddy, the link I provided above seems to match your case exactly and it has around 10 answers. Follow them and if none work dewcribe here what you tried and how it fails

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo I will try all the answers there. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need `__init__.py` if you're using `Python 3`. The following structure should work:

```
run.py
includes/
    funcs.py
```

If you're running this script from the folder with your `run.py` then the following should work:

```py
from includes import funcs
```

Comment: Thanks @triwz. :) I still get the same error. The file `run.py` has `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top. Does that change anything?

Comment: @RealNoob Do you use Linux? Usually, it is `python3` as `python` is referring to Python 2. You can try to run the script from the terminal with `python3 run.py` to ignore the shebang line (`#!`)

Comment: @triwz I am on windows and I run `run.py` through command line. :)